# Why the observable collection returns correct number of objects but the object are empty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following service

```
    @Injectable()
export class LMSVideoResulful { 
    getVideos( enrolmentId : number ) :Observable<Array<Video>> {
        var x = new Array<Video>();
        //https://www.youtube.com/embed/MV0vLcY652c
        x.push( new Video( "SQL 1", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qMvDsarDdK0", "sdsdssdss" ));
        x.push( new Video( "SQL 2", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hVBALRtY8g0", "sdsdssdss" ));
        x.push( new Video( "SQL 3", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qMvDsarDdK0", "sssdssds" ));
        x.push( new Video( "SQL 4", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Fo_KTDrBSU", "sdsdssdss" ));
        return from([x]);
    }
}
```

Here is the video model

```
export class Video{
    constructor(
        
        title : string,
        videoUrl: string,
        description : string
    ){}
}
```

In the component's constructor  i call the service as

```
constructor( private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public myVideoService : LMSVideoResulful ){//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm196HOdSzI
    

    this.safeURL = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/MV0vLcY652c");

    
    this.myVideoService.getVideos(1).subscribe( x => {
      this.videoList = x;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    }, error => error)
    
    
   
  }
```

Even there are four objects sent through the service the `console.log()` line shows array of four objects but the objects are empty

[image]

Why this happens and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because most likely you have not assigned the values in the constructor to the member variables of your class. Due to which you get the object printed out, but with no properties.

Make sure that the class `Video` is defined as below:

```
export class Video {

  constructor(private seq: string, private url: string, private desc: string) { }

}
```

You need to declare the variables in the constructor with *any access specifier*. That then becomes a shorthand notation for assigning the values to them. Without them, as you can see the values will not be assigned.

Comment: i have updated my post with the Video class.... and what you have made properties private in your post?

Comment: You need to declare the variables in the constructor with any *access specifier*. That then becomes a shorthand notation for assigning the values to them. Without them, as you can see the values will not be assigned.

Comment: you are absolutely correct....now it working after adding access modifiers, thank you for the insight answer : )